# Экспорт игровой сцены Unity3D на Node.JS сервер

Tags: node.js, unity3d, разработка-игр, 3d

Насколько я понял, для того, чтобы человек не проваливался сквозь текстуры, а пуля при стрельбе через стену не пролетала сквозь нее, необходимо держать физику также на стороне сервера.

Исходя из того, что нагуглил, пришел к выводу, что единственное, что не позволяет мне реализовать все это дело на Node.JS, так это мое незнание того, **каким образом можно перенести игровую сцену в виде координат поверхности карты (террейна) на Node.JS сервер**. Существуют ли какие-нибудь библиотеки для такого, или как это сделать по-другому?

Если я ошибаюсь в возможности реализовать нечто подобное, будьте добры, посоветуйте что-нибудь другое.

Comment: Вопрос, конечно, слишком обширен. Можно попробовать посмотреть как раз в сторону реализации этого в LA2 и геодаты. Поверхностно ознакомиться что это можно http://m-moworld.ru/index.php/topic/4772-sozdanie-i-redaktirovanie-geodaty/   ну или посмотрев в поиске запросом `lineage 2 server geodata редактирование` ......суть в том, чтоб на сервере хранить некое математическое описание террейна с данными об участке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA PhysX же на C++, как вы собираетесь на Node.js с ним работать? Я всего парочку библиотек встречал, которые пытались слинковать node.js и PhysX SDK.

Вы же не собираетесь на Node.js вручную реализовывать всю физику сами?

Это что касается именно Node.js. С другой стороны, чем обусловлено требование использовать node.js? Вы в Unity можете собрать Linux серверный билд без графики, чисто с физикой. Мы так в нашей онлайн игре и поступаем.

Для начала хорошо бы почитать про [концепт сети в Unity3d](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetConcepts.html). Посмотреть [примеры](https://gist.github.com/jamiltron/f27516f54dc1b3ab14fc), как [реализовать](http://www.robotmonkeybrain.com/good-enough-guide-to-unitys-unet-transport-layer-llapi/). Так вообще можно с помощью high-level api всё делать или работать с low-level api (LLAPI). Мы используем именно LLAPI.

Comment: Пожалуй, node.js привлекателен молниеносной скоростью разработки всех модулей, не связанных с физикой (инвентарь, чат, квесты и т.д.).

Comment: Забавно, но по запросу в гугле "серверный билд unity3d" мой вопрос находится уже на пятом месте)

Comment: @ВасилийУкин node.js однопоточный. Возможно с этим в будущем будут проблемы.

Comment: а в случае с uNet (или как эта штука называется, когда сервер с помощью самого Unity сделан) все будет как надо? Сложно сформулировать четкий вопрос, поэтому просто спрошу: про что мне почитать, чтобы вникнуть во все это (для реализации сервера на самом Unity)

Comment: @ВасилийУкин обновил ответ, добавил пару ссылок.

Comment: @ВасилийУкин , Suvitruf а как реализован SmartFoxServer, который на Java и не имеет визуальной части? Там никаким билдом юнити в качестве сервера не пахнет вообще. но с игрой на юнити взаимодействует неплохо. Кстати, хоть LineAge2 не на юнити, однако серверная часть на с++, а у её клонов на Java и они спокойно справляются с расчетом физики. Всё упирается в то, что это сложно сделать, но все таки возможно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а там разве физику завезли? Там есть поддержка работы с Unet, но не припоминаю, чтоб там физика была.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал посмотреть в сторону baas, например тот же gamesparks. А физика не должна считаться на сервере (иначе сервер припухнет) имхо сервер максимум должен валидировать расчеты на стороне клиента и результаты этих расчетов через него проходящие.  P.s. у меня вообще такое ощущение что речь в вопросе не о том была. Хотелось бы уточнение от автора. Ибо хоть убей не понимаю к чему тут node.js и обсчет физики на сервере.

Comment: @justyx `сервер максимум должен валидировать расчеты на стороне клиента и результаты этих расчетов через него проходящие` без физики, да? )

Comment: Валидировать не означает проводить их целиком :) формально говоря проверять на отклонения от нормы. То есть как пример сервер знает что игрок двигается со скоростью N, на клиенте обсчитываются все перемещения и отдаются серверу, если сервер видит что чото многовато игрок сдвинулся, он ему вернет мол не чувак, максимум до сюда двигайся. В таком ключе.  Мы когда ммо разрабатывали мы даже контроль мобами с сервера на ближайших игроков вешали, кто в пределах чанка находится. По максимуму выносить с сервера все что можно обсчитать на клиенте, а на сервере лишь подтвердить.